# How to close a Java Stream?

Tags: java, stream, try-catch

Whenever I see Java 6 Stream handling it's done pretty much like this:

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception
{
    InputStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = connection.openConnection();
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        if( stream != null )
        {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I fail to see why this is necessary. Wouldn't this work the same way?

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception
{
    InputStream stream = connection.openConnection();

    try
    {
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

If `openConnection()` fails then `stream` won't be assigned and then there's nothing to close anyway, isn't it?

Comment: it will throw an exception if connection.openConnection() fail.. your try and finally has no sense, and suppose that don't fail and is null `stream` then in finally will throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Yes, but what is hidden by the dots if of course interaction with the stream that may trigger an IOException.

Comment: @nachokk but the method already `throws Exception`. Also, probably any operation with the `stream` could throw an `Exception` as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yep has no sense using try clause i think..

Comment: @nachokk it has, it closes the resources in the `finally` block.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but think that only `openConnection` throws IOException.. you make try finally cause runtimeExceptions then.. btw throws Exception is ugly

Comment: @nachokk you can execute another operation using the `stream` that could throw an `IOException` or another `Exception`, so even if there is any you should catch it and use the `finally` block to close the open resources.

Comment: @nachokk You're missing the point here. It's not about catching anything. There isn't event a catch block. It's all forwarded to the method caller.

Comment: @Taig nop, cause you can lose exceptions in that way..see what i comment below in answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you.

That extra step with the `null` assignment is unnecessary and ugly. You can even make `stream` final.

The only time I would write something like this is if you have more than one resource that needs to be cleaned up (happens with JDBC a lot), and you want to avoid multiple nested try/finally blocks (but usually I go for those anyway).

And with Java 7, you can use the try-with construct.

Comment: im not agree at all, in that way you can lose exceptions..consider that something wrong happen business exception, then stream is null... then stream.close() will throw NullPointerException and you lose business exception.. making final stream solves this example but..

Comment: `Stream.close()` will never be called because the method won't terminate after the IOException is thrown in the first line.

Comment: you don't specify what happen in `try block` if a business exception is throw there and `stream` is null then you'll lose exception.

Comment: How could `stream` possibly be `null` when the `try` block is being executed? Just as Thilo mentioned it could as well be final.

Comment: @nachokk: With `final` you can make sure that `stream` will never be null in the `try` or `finally` blocks.

Comment: @Taig you have to add to the question then, but the noise of the code is `throws Exception` that is what i really don't like..

Comment: @nachokk: Let me add my voice to all the others that told you that the `throws Exception` has *nothing* to do with the question. You might as well complain about the `...` being a syntax error in the try block.

Comment: xD could be an array hihi, no problem but stream as `final` is a must i still think

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you are retrieving an InputStream with a construct like

```
InputStream stream = connection.openConnection();
```

there are three possible outcomes: Either the method returns a proper `InputStream`, or it returns `null`, or it throws an exception.

Let's look at all three possibilities:

1) The method returned a proper input stream.

In that case the try block just continues, and if it does not encounter any other problems (aka exceptions), it just normally ends after also executing the finally block.

2) The method returns null.

In that case you also should have a null check inside the try block. If so, your try block normally just does nothing and the finally block must also have the null check. Otherwise your finally block would throw a NPE.

If you do not guard against the null return, your code inside the try block will throw the NPE (I assume the stream variable is used there). In that case, the finally block will be executed and would again throw a NPE, if it had not the null check. In the latter case, only the second NPE from the finally block is actually thrown to the caller.

3) The method call for retrieving the input stream throws an exception.

In that case the try block will end, which immediately causes the finally block to execute, and then the method will end abruptly. But with which exception? That depends.

Consider the thrown exception is an IOException, which in most cases will be thrown. First of all, the variable will still have the null reference! The finally block then would again throw an NPE, if it had not the null check. In that case, the first exception (the IOE) will be forgotten, because only the NPE would be passed to the called of your method. That's not a good idea.

All in all, the null check is indeed necesary.

Now comes Java 7 with its try-with-resources construct. This is indeed a much better mechanism, as it has an implicit finally block, where the streams are closed. If there is an exception in the try block, and the implicit finally block also throws an exception, tnow the first exception (from inside the try block) will be passed to the caller. That is much mor appropriate. And the syntax is much better to read.

Comment: 2) There are no hints in the Java doc that `URL.openConnection()` could possibly return `null`. If it does my could would fail, that's true.
3) Please note that the `URL.openConnection()` is not called from within the `try` block. Therefore finally won't be executed. The method execution will stop at the first line and forward an `IOException`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Both code snippets are technically equivalent. Indeed, I always used a static utility method for "quietly" closing a stream, which already used only one line of code. This is more common, but also has become obsolete with the try-with-resources statement of Java 7.